# jQuery on click on a child element add class to a non-direct parent

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menu, click

I am using the code below to add a class to my menu section when I hover an item on my menu :

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery('.has-children').hover(function(){     
           jQuery('.header-jr').addClass('br-top-only');    
       },function(){    
          jQuery('.header-jr').removeClass('br-top-only');     
       });
   });
</script>
```

It works great but now I need to transform this function in a function that add/remove the class only when I click (not hover) on an item. I thought the following function would work, but it did not (nothing happend and no error in consol).

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery('.has-children').click(function(){     
           jQuery('.header-jr').addClass('br-top-only');    
       },function(){    
          jQuery('.header-jr').removeClass('br-top-only');     
       });
   });
</script>
```

Can someone help me with this. I must confess, I have almost 0 knowledge in jQuery/JS so if you could give me a simple solution that would help me a lot.

PS1 : **.has-children** is my CHILD and **.header-jr** is my PARENT.

PS2 : the child ".has-children" is not directly below the parent ".header-jr" in my code, I have like 5/6 div between so I think that I can't use "parent" in jQuery.

---

**EDIT (SOLUTION)** : I found a solution to my demand + to an additionnal issue (who was that I needed to remove the class if I click elsewhere on the page, something that I could not achieve with only a function toggleClass).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('.has-children').on('click', function(event){  
       jQuery('.header-jr').toggleClass('br-top-only');    
   });});

jQuery(document).click(function(e) {                    
   if(!jQuery(e.target).hasClass('has-children') )
   {
       jQuery('.header-jr').removeClass('br-top-only');               
   }
});
```

It might not be optimal at all but I am not a jQuery pro and it fit my need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the page load (i.e. by clicking a button) you need to use event delegation by using jquery , `.on()`

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

Try with toggleClass like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('.has-children').on('click', function(event){  
       jQuery('.header-jr').toggleClass('br-top-only');    
   });});
```

If you want to toggle 2 classes br-top-only and other_class then use like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('.has-children').on('click', function(event){  
       jQuery('.header-jr').toggleClass('br-top-only other_class');    
   });});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, your solution work perfectly. Can I just ask how can i "untoggle" the class if the user THEN click elsewhere ? I tried to add a removeClass but it break my code :(

Comment: toggleClass method is add or remove class. so no need anything.

Comment: I understand it remove the class if I click again on the children. But If I click on an other element on the page, is there a way to remove the class ?

Comment: Where you used this header-jr -> br-top-only class it's remove.

Comment: I find a solution, I edited my question to add it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) like:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.has-children').click(function() {
    jQuery('.header-jr').toggleClass('br-top-only');  
  });
});
```

```css
.br-top-only{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='header-jr'>
  <div class='otherdiv'>text</div>
  <div class='otherdiv'>text</div>
  <div class='otherdiv'>text</div>
  <div class='has-children'>text</div>
</div>
```

If you have multiple `header` and `has child`:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.has-children').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).parent('.header-jr').toggleClass('br-top-only');  
  });
});
```

```css
.br-top-only{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='header-jr'>
  <div class='otherdiv'>text</div>
  <div class='otherdiv'>text</div>
  <div class='otherdiv'>text</div>
  <div class='has-children'>text</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class='header-jr'>
  <div class='otherdiv'>text</div>
  <div class='otherdiv'>text</div>
  <div class='otherdiv'>text</div>
  <div class='has-children'>text</div>
</div>
```

If you have multiple level of `divs` you need to use [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.has-children').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).closest('.header-jr').toggleClass('br-top-only');
  });
});
```

```css
.br-top-only {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='header-jr'>
  <div>
    <div class='otherdiv'>text</div>
    <div class='otherdiv'>text</div>
    <div class='otherdiv'>text</div>
    <div class='has-children'>text</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class='header-jr'>
  <div>
    <div class='otherdiv'>text</div>
    <div class='otherdiv'>text</div>
    <div class='otherdiv'>text</div>
    <div class='has-children'>text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```